# Unable to start zookeeper getting exception saying that unable to load

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am unable to start zookeeper in my local
getting exception

Error: Could not find or load main class software\kafka_2.12-2.3.0\libs\activation-1.1.1.jar;

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error.
Finally I found the reason.
I put kafka in a folder which it's name contains space like this
C:\Open source\kafka\kafka_2.12-2.3.0
Then I copied all kafka_2.12-2.3.0 to a new folder without space in name, such asc C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.0

and kafka can run
NOte that the command line is: zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties
NOT: zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties

Here's my result 
[image]